# My Firebase website did not deploy and I followed the documentation

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

When I click on the URL on my Firebase website it will go to the Firebase hosting site:
https://mi-fabuloso-proyecto-f1736.firebaseapp.com/

I typed on the terminal "$ npm install -g firebase-tools, $ firebase login, $ firebase init", and "$ firebase deploy"

```
firebase.json

      {
        "database": {
          "rules": "database.rules.json"
        },
        "hosting": {
          "public": "dist",
          "ignore": [
            "firebase.json",
            "**/.*",
            "**/node_modules/**"
          ],
          "rewrites": [
            {
              "source": "**",
              "destination": "/index.html"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

On the browser appear this:
https://mi-fabuloso-proyecto-f1736.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: The index seems to be going to that particular URL.

Comment: Could you check `index.html` file is inside `dist` folder?

Comment: yes, index.html is inside dist folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left the default index.html and **everything** is set to go there because of:

```
"rewrites": [
            {
              "source": "**",
              "destination": "/index.html"
            }
          ]
```